# Node expressJS variables to client and Back

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, client

Ok building my first node project with expressJS.
So i have a Jquery script that runs on the client side and it fills a JSON object with items chosen by the user.

- I want to pass this information back to the node backend so that I can add it to a mongo DB. Can I post and retrieve this data from a common area or something?
- I will also need to pass the information from the node backend back to the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider writing a REST API and calling that through the client.  This should start you in the right direction:  http://webapplog.com/express-js-4-node-js-and-mongodb-rest-api-tutorial/

edit: there are many tutorials on the subject.  Google can help "Node Express REST"

Answer (score 0):

you should take a look to http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.VERB

express allow you to user all "REST verbs" (get,post,delete,put) to handle all queries that your front app can send.